# Cross Validation With Repetition

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, cross-validation, knn

I have a question regarding the cross validation used in ML problems.If we apply 5-folds cross validation for a dataset say for example 2 times, one in Monday and one in Friday, just two separate times. Does the elements that exist in a particular fold in Monday are the same elements that would exist in the same fold in Friday?

Does this explain why this code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

iris=load_iris()

X=iris.data
y=iris.target
model=KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

cvs=cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=5)
print(cvs)
```

gives always the same results in every execution:

```
[0.96666667 1.         0.93333333 0.96666667 1.        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read in the [documentation of cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html?highlight=cross_val_score#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score), under the hood it performs a [Stratified K-Folds](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) cross validation which does not shuffle your data (X, y). Therefore, each time you calculate the `cross_val_score` you train the same model on the same folds and validate on the same fold and therefore obtain the same result.